# Scrapy crawling same page over and over again for different urls on german site

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to extract info on flats/rooms from a German site called [WG-Gesucht](http://www.wg-gesucht.de/wohnungen-in-Berlin.8.2.0.2.html). I kinda figured out that their links follow the logic:

```
http:// www.wg-gesucht.de/wohnungen-in-Berlin.8.2.0.**X**.html`
```

where `X=0, 1, 2, ...`

When I paste the links into my browser, they do work perfectly. However my optimism was shattered when I tried crawling those links. In the end I only get entries corresponding to `X = 0` in my database.

Here is my spider:

```
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import Join, MapCompose

from scraper_app.items import WGGesuchtEntry




class WGGesuchtSpider(Spider):
    """Spider for wg-gesucht.de, Berlin"""
    name = "wggesucht"
    allowed_domains = ["wg-gesucht.de"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.wg-gesucht.de/wohnungen-in-Berlin.8.2.0.0.html"]
    # start_urls = ["http://www.wg-gesucht.de/wohnungen-in-Berlin.8.2.0.%s.html"%x for x in range(0,1)]


    entries_list_xpath = '//tr[contains(@id,"ad--")]'
    item_fields = {
        # 'title': './/span[@itemscope]/meta[@itemprop="name"]/@content',
        'rooms': './/td[2]/a/span/text()',
        'entry_date': './/td[3]/a/span/text()',
        'price': './/td[4]/a/span/b/text()',
        'size': './/td[5]/a/span/text()',
        'district': './/td[6]/a/span/text()',
        'start_date': './/td[7]/a/span/text()',
        'end_date': './/td[8]/a/span/text()',
        'link': './/@adid'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in xrange(1, 10):
            url = 'http://www.wg-gesucht.de/wohnungen-in-Berlin.8.2.0.' + str(i) + '.html'
            yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_items)


    def parse_items(self, response):
        """
        Default callback used by Scrapy to process downloaded responses

        # Testing contracts:
        # @url http://www.livingsocial.com/cities/15-san-francisco
        # @returns items 1
        # @scrapes title link

        """
        selector = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        # iterate over deals
        for entry in selector.xpath(self.entries_list_xpath):
            loader = XPathItemLoader(WGGesuchtEntry(), selector=entry)

            # define processors
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(unicode.strip)
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()

            # iterate over fields and add xpaths to the loader
            for field, xpath in self.item_fields.iteritems():
                loader.add_xpath(field, xpath)
            yield loader.load_item()
```

Should I maybe use the `CrawlSpider` instead of `Spider`?

Any suggestions are mostly welcome, thank you!

Comment: how do you know that you are only getting items from X=0? by the `title`? `rooms`? logs show the spider is not going through the other urls?

Comment: by looking at the 'link' field in the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like a cookies problems, you can check that by opening a new browser and trying directly the [6th page](http://www.wg-gesucht.de/wohnungen-in-Berlin.8.2.0.6.html) for example, you are going to receive the response of the **first** page.

Scrapy tries to use cookies for subsequent requests, so one way of solving this would be not iterating the requests to the page, but making one after the other like:

```
import re

start_urls = [http://example.com/0.html]

def parse(self, response):
    cur_index = response.meta.get('cur_index', 1)
    ...
    new_url = # use the response.url to change to the following url (+1 to the index)
    if cur_index < 10:
        yield Request(new_url, callback=self.parse, meta={'cur_index': cur_index+1})
```

Comment: Thank you! I cannot upvote due to lack of reputation, but it worked brilliantly. Just out of curiosity: how did you see that it is a cookies problem?

Comment: just explained that on the first paragraph of the answer. There is no right procedure, you just need to keep trying.

Comment: @eLRuLL maybe this is a trivial question. Why does it open the first page on hitting the 6th? I mean what does the cookie save so that this happens?

Comment: @Mellkor information about your session, they are extra information required by a request. so a unique request is not only specified by a URL, but a combination of url, headers, cookies, method, data, etc.